# How do I color in two different colors one square function?

Tags: pgfplots

[image: This is one square function displayed with \foreach and \addplot]
I need to color every other line of this same function in orange and make it dashed, but this is only one square function, so can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Can you copy that part of the code from your document and edit your question to add it?

Comment: there you go, that's the function I need to draw with tikz, and I need to have every second line of the function orange dashed

Comment: @DenisMuratovic: It would be great if you could add the code as copyable text, not as an image, so people don't have to re-type the code by hand if they want to work on an answer.

Comment: Copy as in paste the text, not the image. :) Also, post the full MWE (minimal code necessary to create that image), not just the snippet.

Comment: This seems to be part of an assignment. Out of interest, can you link the course material?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some ways you can do it:

1. Same as [Thruston's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286293/4778) to this same question, lets you use `\ifodd` in TikZ as well. But we add a counter using `count=\xi` (default starting from 1) so that it alternates between blue+solid and orange+dashed.
2. You can set a `cycle list name`, defined here as `mycycle` and there write your various style in order. Since we write two, they will alternate. Don't forget to write your command as `\addplot+[...]`, note the `+` and the optional arguments `[...]`.

Here's the output, it's the same for all the solutions provided. The codes for the various solutions are provided below.

### Output

[image]

### Using `\ifodd`

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    grid=major,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-20,ymax=20,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$
    ]
\foreach \a [count=\xi] in {-2.4,-2.1,...,2.4}
{%
    \ifodd\xi
        \addplot[blue, line width=.5pt] plot expression {\a*(\x^2)-3*\x +cos(90*\x)};
    \else
        \addplot[orange, dashed, line width=.5pt] plot expression {\a*(\x^2)-3*\x+cos(90*\x)};
    \fi
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Using `cycle list name`

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycycle}{%
    {blue}, 
    {dashed,orange}% <--- % must be there for this to work properly!
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    grid=major,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-20,ymax=20,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    cycle list name=mycycle
    ]

\foreach \a in {-2.4,-2.1,...,2.4}
{%
    \addplot+[smooth,line width=.5pt] plot expression {\a*(\x^2)-3*\x +cos(90*\x)};
}
\end{axis}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry guys for uploading only an image, first time here asking questions, next time I will put the text of code and thank you very much, im new to latex and still trying to figure out all possibilities, and again, thank you very much.

Comment: @DenisMuratovic No problem. :D

Comment: @Alenanno is there any way to "inline" the `if` construct?  So that you did not need to repeat the long and complex expression?

Comment: @Thruston Let me look into it.

Comment: @Thruston Added one alternative solution. I'm working on another one, but it refuses to work. :D

Answer (score 7):

In [Metapost](http://tug.org/metapost.html) you could just wrap the colour specification in a `if ... else ... fi` construct.  Like this:

```
draw ...  if odd i: dashed evenly withcolor marmelade else: withcolor sky fi;
```

Here's a complete version of your plot.

[image]

```
prologues:=3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

vardef f(expr a,x) = a*(x*x)-3x+cosd(90x) enddef;

numeric u, v, s, a, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;
-xmin = xmax = 5;  u = 1cm;
-ymin = ymax = 20; v = 2mm;
s = 1/8;

color marmelade, sky;
marmelade = 0.67(red + 1/2 green);
sky = 0.54[blue,white];

for i=-8 upto 8:
  a := 0.3i;
  draw ((xmin,f(a,xmin))
     for x = xmin+s step s until xmax:
        -- (x,f(a,x))
     endfor) 
     xscaled u yscaled v
     if odd i: dashed evenly withcolor marmelade else: withcolor sky fi;
endfor
clip currentpicture to ( (xmin,ymin) -- (xmax,ymin) -- (xmax, ymax) -- (xmin,ymax) -- cycle) xscaled u yscaled v;

path xx, yy, bar;
xx = ((xmin,0)--(xmax,0)) scaled u;
yy = ((0,ymin)--(0,ymax)) scaled v;

defaultfont := "texnansi-lmr10";
string minus_sign; minus_sign = char 143;

for i=-20 step 10 until 20: 
   bar := xx shifted (0,i*v);
   draw bar if i<>0: withcolor .7 white  fi; 
   label.lft(if i<0: minus_sign & fi decimal abs(i), point 0 of bar);
endfor
for i= -4 step  2 until  4: 
   bar := yy shifted (i*u,0);
   draw bar if i<>0: withcolor .7 white fi; 
   label.bot(if i<0: minus_sign & fi decimal abs(i), point 0 of bar);
endfor     

setbounds currentpicture to bbox currentpicture scaled 1.03;
endfig;
end.
```

Comment: PS.  I know the question is about pgfplots, but I thought it would be useful to show how it could be done in MP.  Plain MP gives you lots of flexibility, but you have to do all the things like the grid and the axes from scratch.  You pays your money, and you takes your choice.

Comment: @Huugo Where is the reference? The colors?

Comment: Check the color definitions @Alenanno

Comment: @Huugo Lucy in the sky with diamonds?

Comment: Yap, @Alenanno. That's what came to my mind, at least :)

Comment: @Huugo, it was sort of accidental, but then it has been [hard to avoid their music recently](http://recode.net/2015/12/23/heres-the-list-of-streaming-services-that-will-have-the-beatles-tomorrow/)

Comment: @Alenanno well the plot does look slightly like a bad trip.